# Does Ryzen 5 7640U CPU have SMT always enabled?

Tags: cpu, amd-ryzen

I'm having a hard time finding data sheets for AMD CPUs, so I decided to ask here.

Motherboard manufacturer ASRock claims that AMD Ryzen 5 7640U CPU doesn't allow to disable SMT.

Is that accurate? AFAIK, most AMD desktop CPUs allow to disable SMT, so this seems to be a strange exception. Is there a reason behind it?

Comment: I am not aware of any AMD processors that is supported that doesn’t support SMT.

Comment: @Ramhound So am I, but the question is about disabling SMT.